# How to rewrite URL using Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, vanity-url

I have a simple question, but I couldn't find the way to do it in my script.

Instead of this:

```
http://www.mySite.com/player.php?id=3773
```

I need this:

```
http:/www.mySite.com/europe/spain/real-madrid/cristiano-ronlado/
```

Comment: Search for `short urls`, its all over SO and the internet.

Comment: And `vanity urls`, along with `htaccess rewrites`. If you are going to do this, make sure you are using absolute links in your documents, very important!

Comment: The maintainers of this site, jeff and joel ask that you don't respond to questions, no matter how poor they are, to advise them to "do a google search".  The proper response is to down vote the question, the last thing the internet needs is to have someone land on a stackoverflow page, and read it, to find out that they should "do a google search".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples and tutorials all over the internet for this, you just need to search for the right keywords. Some examples:

1. Vanity URL's
2. Clean URL's
3. `.htaccess` rewrites
4. SEO friendly URL's

One site that I found helpful when learning about `.htaccess` rewrites was this one:

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

and a more friendly one:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

It teaches you the basic stuff, but also goes into the deeper more complex stuff.

**Useful Tip**

One thing that is very important, otherwise you will run into issues with linked files, is to use absolute links in your HTML.

So instead of this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/stylsheet.css" />`

You need to specify the whole address like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.net/css/stylsheet.css" />`

The reason why the above is necessary is because you are telling the server to interpret `example.net/blah/blah/blah/` as `example.net/blah.php?id=123`, but the browser only sees it as `example.net/blah/blah/blah` and therefore the relative links get broken.

**UPDATE**

One additional thing to mention is that whilst this is handled server side, it is not PHP that handles the rewrite, it is Apache.